# WPF XAML Datagrid XML File Binding with XElement, XML File Loaded in codebehind

Tags: wpf, xml, binding, datagrid, xelement

Here we go again kids, yet another camper lost in the woods around WPF Databinding.  Its been a fruitful day of climbing the databinding inverted ice wall, but I'm at my wits end with this.  No examples I find or amount of SNOOP'ing is helping me find my issue.  Hopefully some databinding rock star, all three of you, can help a brotha out!  :)

**XML File** - The faces and names have been changed to protect the innocent

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Mappings>
  <Mapping>
    <Class1>WonderBread</Class1>
    <Class2>Tortilla</Class2>
    <Properties>
      <Property>
        <Jx>name</Jx>
        <Dyn>Name</Dyn>
        <Create>1</Create>
        <Update>0</Update>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Jx>Juice</Jx>
        <Dyn>Juice</Dyn>
        <Create>1</Create>
        <Update>0</Update>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Jx>Fred</Jx>
        <Dyn>Fred</Dyn>
        <Create>1</Create>
        <Update>0</Update>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Jx>Love</Jx>
        <Dyn>Love</Dyn>
        <Create>1</Create>
        <Update>0</Update>
      </Property>
    </Properties>
  </Mapping>
</Mappings>
```

**How I load this XML File** and set it into my datagrids DataContext. Done in the constructor.  This loads correctly, via SNOOP I can see the XML file in the DataContext.

```
    // load the ObjectMappingXML file and set as Gridview Context
    XEClassMappings = XElement.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClassMappingXML"]);
    dgMapping.DataContext = XEClassMappings;
```

**XAML code to display the content**

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgMapping" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[Property]}" Height="569">
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="JxAPI Prop" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Jx].Value}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dyn Prop" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Dyn].Value}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

What in the name of all that is holy am I missing?  8hrs of hopeful F5s has left me at wits end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to reach to the properties element. Change your ItemsSource binding to below:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgMapping" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Element[Mapping].Element[Properties].Elements[Property]}" Height="569">
```

It will work.

Hope it helps